# Ajax call in my aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to give a call to my function "InsertMethod" using Ajax but the function is not being called.
But if i use the same code as below in new page then its works i.e. call to function is given using Ajax. Can anyone please help me out regarding this.
And i have one more query. I cannot access any control of page in that web method "Insertmethod"

below is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getDistinctChains() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Tax_Type_Master.aspx/InsertMethod',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'Name':'" + TaxType.value + "'}",
            //async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $('[id*=txtTaxtypeName]').val('');
                alert("Record Has been Saved in Database");
            },
            error: function() { //console.log('there is some error'); 
                alert('there is some error');
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[id*=ImageSaveFooter]').click(function() {
            getDistinctChains();
        });
    });
</script>
```

below is my cs code

```
public partial class Tax_Type_Master : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Generic gn = new Generic();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Master.FillHeader("Tax Type Master");
                BindGrid();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Master.ErrorMessage(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat =     
    System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json,
    UseHttpGet = false)]
public static string InsertMethod(string Name)
{
    TextBox TaxTypeName = (TextBox)grd_Master.FooterRow.FindControl("txtTaxtypeName");

    int count = (int)gn.ExecuteScaler("Check_TaxType_Ref_TaxTypeMaster", TaxTypeName.Text.ToUpper().Trim());

    if (count == 0)
    {
        gn.ExecuteNonQuery("Insert_Taxtype_Master",  
        TaxTypeName.Text.ToUpper().Trim());
        BindGrid();
        Master.SuccessMessage("Record Inserted Successfully..");
    }
    else
    {
        Master.ValidationMessage("Record Already Exist..");
    }
    return "True";
}
```

Comment: have you pasted code correctly? document.ready closing bracket }); is after script end tag.

Comment: Its mistake happened while copying the code. I have corrected the code

Comment: check url, try `/Tax_Type_Master.aspx/InsertMethod`

Comment: you can not to access controls in static methods

Comment: Is there any other way to access controls

Comment: I tried  url /Tax_Type_Master.aspx/InsertMethod but its not working

Comment: your code is fine make sure all your methods including web methods should be inside `public partial class Tax_Type_Master : System.Web.UI.Page
{}`

Comment: Thanks ,
but is is included properly in public partial class Tax_Type_Master : System.Web.UI.Page {}

Comment: @shariqueansari: that code is not fine. period.

Comment: @naveen i don't mean method body. i tried the same code by commenting webmethod body except `return "True";` it was working fine. if you want i can paste my code as answer.

Comment: @poonam i can see you defined web method `InsertMethod` outside this class `Tax_Type_Master`, move it to class `Tax_Type_Master` & try again. Are you using any update panel?

Comment: @shariqueansari: got it

Comment: @shariqueansari : please paste the code

Comment: @poonam i can paste but i have commented all the lines in `webmethod` as you can't access control in static method, see my answer  it will work for you . [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768232/ajax-call-in-my-aspx-page/29769049#29769049)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what version of jquery you are using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one alternate you can use query string like this:-

```
http://localhost/Tax_Type_Master.aspx?m=InsertMethod
```

on page load to call InsertMethod use this:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys() ||
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["m"]))
        {
            var m = Request.QueryString["m"];

            switch (m)
            {
                case "InsertMethod":
                    InsertMethod("Name");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Your `InsertMethod` is like this:-

```
public void InsertMethod(string Name)
    {
        Page.Controls.Add(new Literal(){Text = "<script>alert('method called');</script>"});
    }
```

Modify your ajax call like this:-

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'Tax_Type_Master.aspx?m=InsertMethod',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'Name':'" + "asdf" + "'}",
            //async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.d) {
                    $('[id*=txtTaxtypeName]').val('');
                    alert("Record Has been Saved in Database");
                }
            },
            error: function () { //console.log('there is some error'); 
                alert('there is some error');
            }
        });
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

> And i have one more query. I cannot access any control of page in that web method "Insertmethod"

It's the way it should be, you cannot access the Page Control via PageMethod as *they are static and have no access to the page's control collection*.

From your code, its evident that you use a textbox. So just add a `CssClass` to access it like this in the ajax method.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTaxtypeName" runat="server" CssClass="myclass"></asp:TextBox>
```

Change your ajax call like this so that you can access the footer row like this.

```
function getDistinctChains() {
    var DTO = { Name = $(".myclass").val() };
    $.ajax({
        .....
        data: JSON.stringify( DTO ),
        success: function(response) {
            .....
        },
        error: function() { 
            .....
        }
    });
}
```

---

That being said, this is bad design as you cannot bind an `asp:GridView` in a `PageMethod`. What you are trying to do is to insert a value to the database ( if its unique ) and re-bind the `GridView` using the PageMethod. Insertion would would just fine. But the `BindGrid()` method won't work as its cannot access `grd_Master` from a static method.

You must either use an `UpdatePanel` or use a third party plugin like [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/) or [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

For further info, read this. http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/